# Why xcode project option form label smash with textfield

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new in **xcode** and ios development, face problem on xcode "chosen option for your new project" option ,this form label and textfield are smash like picture bellow. What to do how to? How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: This is Xcode issue. Are you facing this issue consistently? If NO Quit the Xcode and open it again.

Comment: this is a mac os Sierra issue so when new os update will come then may be it will resolve

Comment: iOS Developer,thanks for your reply,yah! you are right i install Sierra today and get the problem.What to do? if i am not wrong will i uninstall the Sierra,then tell me how to uninstall this.Thanks for all.